# Firebase Anonymous Authentication issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase

I am using Firebase Simple Login (version 1.6.1) to authenticate anonymously. I start with,

```
var livepolling_ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(livepolling_ref, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('An error!');
    } else if (user) {
        //Boot the App and save the user.id
        //I'm able to reach this point in the code using the debugger
    }
});

auth.login('anonymous');
```

I have checked that user has a uid and a FirebaseAuthToken in the callback, and I save the user id. So it seems that I am logged in.

However, I have the following security on my entire Firebase repo.

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

When I check the Chrome Console, it tells me "permission denied."

Comment: There's not enough info here to reproduce this or help out. Could you start with version info, and a short example we could run to see the problem? Have you checked the error callbacks to ensure user is actually logged in? Have you checked the JavaScript console? There's not enough here to know where to start.

Comment: I've edited my original post!

Comment: Great detective work! Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my mistake--I was referencing the wrong Firebase Repo. Sorry for the confusion!